# Mutual Information in the presence of noise

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information, noise

Let Y=X+N, where N is the noise distribution.

a. A user can observe only Y. (I(X; Y)=?)
b. A user can estimate the mean of N and he can observe Y only. (I(X;Y|mean(N))) He has no information regarding X.

How do I compare these two scenarios, to prove that in case 2, the user has more information? I tried using mutual information but nothing fruitful was deduced.

Comment: Please specify what the distributions of $X$ and $N$ are.

Comment: Distribution is not specified, we can assume that X and N are normal distributions